# "No Wi-Fi adapter found" help

Tags: wireless, adapter

I installed Ubuntu for the first time yesterday, and I was really enjoying it. But when I woke up this morning I couldn't connect to wifi because "No Wi-Fi adapter found"
I have an HP laptop and my wifi adapter is Releatek RTL8188EE wireless network adapter
I have looked at other posts but couldn't find a fix.
Can someone help me get wifi up and running again?

Comment: Is it possible you were running the 5.4 kernel which all new installs do and it updated to 5.8 which most installs will? If so on startup choose adv and load the 5.4 kernel and see if that works.

Comment: Can you tell me how to try that?

Comment: When you boot and at the grub menu choose Ubuntu adv and then from the next menu choose the 5.4 kernel.

Comment: Grub menu? I just boot into Ubuntu when I boot

Comment: Hit the shift key as it reboots. Look at this other question for more help https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time